How to determine the sign of sensitivity for the eigenvalues with respect to the elements of a square matrix?
For a square matrix $\mathbf{A}$, its right eigenvector $\mathbf{u}$ satisfying:
$$\mathbf{A}\mathbf{u} = \lambda\mathbf{u}$$
, where $\lambda$ is one of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$. Besides, the left eigenvector $\mathbf{v}$ of $\mathbf{A}$ satisfying:
$$\mathbf{A}\mathit{^T}\mathbf{v} = \lambda\mathbf{v}$$
As we known, the sensitivity $\mathit{p}\mathit{_i}\mathit{_j}$ for $\lambda$ with respect to the $\mathit{i}$th row $\mathit{j}$th column element of $\mathbf{A}$ is the product of the $\mathit{i}$th element of $\mathbf{v}$ and the $\mathit{j}$th element of $\mathbf{u}$, i.e.
$$\mathit{p}\mathit{_i}\mathit{_j}=\frac{\partial{\lambda}}{\partial{\mathbf{A}\mathit{_i}\mathit{_j}}} = \mathbf{v}\mathit{_i}\mathbf{u}\mathit{_j}$$
The question is: Since $\mathbf{v}$ and $(\mathbf{-}\mathbf{v})$ are both the left eigenvector of $\mathbf{A}$ (as well as $\mathbf{u}$ and $(\mathbf{-}\mathbf{u})$), how to determine the sign of $\mathit{p}\mathit{_i}\mathit{_j}$?
